Unity Tilemap Rendering doesn´t work fine. Why its Rendering tiles at first, altough they are behind a other Tile?
I'm creating a Unity project with a tilemap. On this tilemap I place objects via script, which sometimes extend over several tiles. Although it is a 2d game, I use a 3D grid to place tiles on top of each other on the same tilemap.
Here I have the problem that one tile is displayed before the other, even though it is behind it.
Example:
Position of the bottom tile of the latern: (0,0,0)
Position of the middle tile of the latern: (0,1,-1)
Position of the top tile of the latern: (0,2,-2)
Position of the left brown tile: (0,1,0)
Position of the right brown tile: (1,1,0)
Position of the camera: (0,0,-10)
This is what the camera sees:
Camera View
This is the scene view:
Scene View
Here my Settings:
Grid Settings
Tilemap Settings
Can someone help me please? :D
(I have the version 2021.3.0f1)
I would expect it to display the lantern completely above the brown tile. I have no idea why that could be...

how exactly are you populating that

Hello BugFinder, sorry but i dont understand your question.

I solved the problem. The cause of the error was a setting on the tilemap renderer. This must have the individual mode.
